# How do I position figures in this grid format (see figure)? Alignment problems

Tags: tables, floats

I want to position 4 figures in the following format:[image: Desired format]

I tried

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
    \multirow{2}{2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{test} } & \multirow{2}{4cm}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{test}} & \includegraphics[scale=1]{test2} \\ 

    & & \includegraphics[scale=1]{test2} \\

\end{document}
```

But I get the result:

[image: Not aligned]

How do I align the figures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabular`s can be nested

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{m{1.2cm}}}
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=2cm]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=2cm]{example-image} &
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image}  \\ \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image} \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if the heights must be the same there is some more work to do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\parbox[][2.5cm][c]{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=2.5cm]{example-image}}
\parbox[][2.5cm][c]{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=2.5cm]{example-image}}
\parbox[][2.5cm][c]{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image}\par\vfill\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image}}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]